# GData is user part of Apps Premier domains or Apps Standard domains

Tags: google-apps, gdata, gdata-api

Is there a way do figure out if a user is part of Apps Premier domains, Apps Standard domains or just a regular google account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I just needed to know this for Google Docs and so my problem was solved with [Accessing Google Docs Metadata feed with gdata-objectivec-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208719/accessing-google-docs-metadata-feed-with-gdata-objectivec-client)