# Accessing Google Docs Metadata feed with gdata-objectivec-client

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gdata-api, google-docs

What's the simplest why to access/parse Google Docs [Metadata feed](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#MetaDataFeed) with [gdata-objectivec-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I overlooked this from the [example](http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Examples/DocsSample/DocsSampleWindowController.m):

```
GDataServiceGoogleDocs *service = [self docsService];
NSURL *entryURL = [GDataServiceGoogleDocs metadataEntryURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];
GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
ticket = [service fetchEntryWithURL:entryURL
                           delegate:self
                  didFinishSelector:@selector(metadataFeedTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
```